# simple uiview change not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to just do a simple view change for proof of concept.

here is the code

```
- (void)swipedScreen
{
    if (self.secondView.superview == nil) {
        [myView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view insertSubview:secondView atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

when I swipe the screen what happens is the view area just goes black... and becomes unresponsive.

I started with a navigatoin app, replaced the tableview with just a standard uiviewcontroller class.. that worked fine..Then i added a secondView (xib only) and changed its class to match the viewcontroller of the first view.

The reason I am finding this difficult is because i am trying to animate the views inside the navigation controller and not push a whole view onto the stack which I am used to doing.

Comment: If it's only for testing purpose, putting up the whole XCode project would make it easier to solve the problem.

Comment: how can I do that? or do you just mean add all of the code? or actually put it somewhere to download?

Comment: just compress and put the file somewhere on the interweb so we can download, scrutinise and debug it.

Comment: okay, put it into my drop box, heres the linke. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53813770/SMPrototype.zip thanks very much for offering your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet that blank unresponsive view is, in reality, your `secondView` object.  I always test by setting `[secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]` and checking if the massive green rectangle actually shows up.

EDIT: having looked at your code, there are multiple problems that arose:

1. You never actually `+alloc` or `-init` anything.
2. You never actually touch those nibs or make a reference to them in code
3. You declare two UIView's as IBOutlets and Strong (two exact opposites, as IBOutlets are __weak, __unsafe_unretained, or assign), yet do not link them to anything.

I've taken the liberty of revising it (sans nibs).  [Take a look](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/SMPrototype.zip).

Comment: dang.. I was hoping that was the problem! but nope still goes black... I think its something to do with the way I am loading my first view.. which happens inside my appDelegate because its a template navigation app //appdelegate **MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];**

Comment: @C.Johns Here, I've taken the liberty of revising your code.  Have at it then: [Dropbox Download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/SMPrototype.zip)

Comment: right so you have made programatic nibs or something here? I am still going over your code to figure out how you have done it.. one interesting thing is that the uilabel stays the stame between views... not sure why this is? thank you very much for the help however! its greatly appreciated and im not trying to learn from it. :P

Comment: No, I made UIViews in code.  Never _ever_ load a UIView from a nib.  Subclass UIView and load your objects from there.

Comment: Anytime.  Was there anything specific you were trying to accomplish with those nibs?

Comment: well, what I thought i was doing was referencing the nibs by linking them to those IBOutlets I made in that class.. Pretty much at the moment I am testing gestures that swipe between different views under the dame navigation controller. The next lot of testing I want to do is place uiwebviews inside those both views to see how swiping views work with those. Man still slightly confused about the way you have done things.. I am gonna read over everything you have said again and see how I feel about it all.. god something so "simple" is quite painful.

Comment: you dont by chance have a tutorial like this that I could walk through  to get a better understanding.

Comment: I'll do you one better: If you want a 'swipe to push' transition, I've [uploaded another example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/SMPrototype%2BNibs.zip) with your code to dropbox (this time with nibs!)

Comment: LOL thats cool, however... this is where I'm having brain explosion, is there a way to do that without **[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];** pretty much what I am trying to avoid is the navigationbar animation like that. (the overall goal is to have a final view, that will display a bunch of different screens (which are the ones i am trying to swipe) inside the navigationcontroller...) I hope this make sense. Question so you code for a living or is this your part time hobby type thing?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Being the animation master that I am, here is a crude [example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/SMPrototype%2BAnims.zip)

Comment: oh my crap that was the stuff right there!! lol flippn cool. well thing is if your interested I might have some contract work for you if you wanna get in touch some how I could explaine it etc.. but hey I would like to thank you heaps for what you have done for me just now! im just shooting off to get some fish and chips ahortly :P then gonna go over this code in more detail to get a better understanding :) Again! thanks a ton your the man!

Comment: No problem, although please, don't hire me (legal reasons, my friend).  I'm here for help anytime at devteam.codafi at GMAIL.com.

Comment: haha, okay man! ill just get the karma gods to send a bunch of karma your way! :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you init the secondView? if init,you can try to set frame for the secondView

Comment: no I have not init, however I have declared them in the .h file.. dose that mean I still have to init it? if so how do you do that.. I am used to just initalizing views I have not declared in the .h file with the ususal classname *newname = [[classname alloc] init]; but with this it wont let me.

Comment: my bad.. secondView = [[UIView alloc] init]; trying it now.

Comment: okay so that still did not solve anything. its till going black and unresponsive..

Answer (score 0):

Your inserting the view at the bottom of the stack,

```
[self.view insertSubview:secondView atIndex:0];
```

Try using addSubview instead.  Also you need to set the views frame somewhere.